# How can I use pytest-cov to both generate a coverage report and also print to terminal?

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, pytest-cov

### Background

I'm new to using pytest and pytest-cov having switched over from unittest + coverage.py

I first set up my automated tests to run in this way:

`python3 -m pytest --cov=myapplication`

which gave me output like this to the terminal:

```
----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.8.5-final-0 -----------
Name                        Stmts   Miss  Cover
-----------------------------------------------
myapplication/__init__.py       0      0   100%
myapplication/file.py          30     30     0%
myapplication/another_file.py  20      6    70%
[...]
-----------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        1195    464    61%
```

Then i wanted to generate an xml report so i changed the command:

`python3 -m pytest --cov-report xml:coverage.xml --cov=myapplication`

### Problem

The problem i'm having is that after adding `--cov-report xml:coverage.xml` i no longer get any output to the terminal

Looking at [the documentation for pytest-cov](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html) i find this:

> These three report options output to files without showing anything on the terminal:
> [goes on to show xml, html and annotation reporting options]

### Question

How can i both generate a report and also print to terminal in the same test run? (Is this even possible?)

(I could run the test suite two times, but if i can i'd like to do everything at once)

---

I am using these versions:

- Python 3.8.5
- pytest 6.2.2 (the latest version as of writing this)
- pytest-cov 2.11.1 (-"-)

Comment: If you run with the `coverage` CLI directly, you can do this I think. https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.4/#quick-start

Comment: You have more control if you split up the test running and the reporting.  Why does pytest have to generate the reports?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Hi and thank you for the comment and perspective, it helps me think about this issue in a different way. Yes maybe that would be best, to just use coverage.py like Paul H suggested. --- One advantage though of using pytest is that i guess there will only be one pass, which would speed things up a bit. (That was an assumption on my part but i haven't been able to verity it)

Comment: It's not faster to use pytest to generate coverage reports.  Run pytest under coverage, either with pytest-cov, or with `coverage run -m pytest`.  Then generate coverage reports from the results.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this by specifying another `--cov-report` argument with one of the terminal output formats. You can have `--cov-report term` or `--cov-report term-missing`. For example:

```
python3 -m pytest --cov-report term --cov-report xml:coverage.xml --cov=myapplication
```

See the [pytest-cov docs you linked to](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reporting.html) for how `term` and `term-missing` work.

Comment: Once you have something like `--cov-report xml:coverage.xml` in your `pyproject.toml` it seems you're stuck with it. I'd like to have both reports in `pyproject.toml` so that my manual command line is `pytest` but still be able to specify only `--cov-report term` in the build pipeline. But `pytest` respects both the `pyproject.toml` and the command line as merged sources and does not over-ride the `pyproject.toml` when only one `--cov-report` is specified on the command line.